# Hibernate: how to auto generate an id that is a 36 base string

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

How do I go around auto generating an `@Id` that is not `Integer/Long` value, but rather a `String` which is a number in base `36`?

e.g. if the next id is to be `58490`, the `String` id attribute should be `194q`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person  {
  @Id
  //?
  private String id;

  @Column
  private String name;
...
}
```

```
+--------+--------+
| base10 | base36 |
+--------+--------+
|    ... | ...    |
|  58490 | 194q   |
|  58491 | 194r   |
+--------+--------+
```

so that the actual `persons` table looks like:

```
+------+------+
|  id  | name |
+------+------+
| ...  | ...  |
| 194q | John |
| 194r | Jack |
+------+------+
```

Comment: Are you want to generate the id then you need to write a custom sequence generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom annotation. [Creating a custom annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation) and put your logic in that annotation.

Another way is to write a converter :

```
public class DecimalToHexConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {


    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {

        // convert to hex
        return object;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        // convert back to decimal
        return object;
    }
}
```

Then apply this converter on your id.

```
  @Id
  @Convert(converter = DecimalToHexConverter.class)
  private String id;
```